# A slice has only one element, named list, why can subslice list[1:] work?

Tags: go

A slice has only one element, named list, why can subslice list[1:] work?
For example:

```
list := []int{1}
fmt.Println(list[1:])
fmt.Println(list[1])
```

The list hasn't the element with index 1, so the third line causes "panic: runtime error: index out of range", but why does the second line works well?

Comment: A slice can have zero elements. `list[1:]` is an example of such a slice.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the language simply *defines* this to be valid.

Think of the indices used in subslicing as pointing "between" elements:

```
Slice a Elements:   | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
Subslice a[2:]              ^===============
Subslice a[2:4]             ^===========^
Subslice a[6:]                              ^
```

Your list[1:] slices of the empty slice.